# Solution of a differential equation in space of distributions

Tags: calculus, distribution-theory

I cant figure out how to find general solution to  equation $(1+x)^2 u''=0$ in the space of distributions. Any ideas?

Comment: What about $u(x)=Cx$?

Comment: It is a solution but not general in the distributions space. Obviously every function which second derivative is $0$ is a solution in the classical sense.

Answer (score 6):

Obviously, supp $u'' \subseteq \{-1\}$, so $ u''$ is linear combination of derivatives of $\delta_{-1}$. As the general solution of $x^2 S = 0$ is $S=c_1\delta + c_2\delta'$, this implies 
$$ u'' = c_1\delta_{-1} + c_2\delta_{-1}'.
$$
and hence
$$ u(x)=c_1(1+x)H(1+x) + c_2H(1+x) + c_3x + c_4
$$
where $H$ denotes the Heaviside function.